# How can I determine how much time a customer has spent speaking to multiple agents

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in which each records the amount of time a customer spent on the phone with an agent, I want to write a formula that averages the total time spent by a user per agent.

```
Customer    Agent   Time spent (MM:SS)

John Smith  Sally Jenkins   1:15
John Smith  Sally Jenkins   2:07
John Smith  Adam  Apple     3:55
John Smith  Adam  Apple     1:42
```

For example, how can I determine the average time John Smith Sent with Sally Jenkins, output that, and then separately determine the average time John Smith spent with Adam apple?

Is that even possible? Any help would appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using the `AVERAGE` function?

Comment: i'll admit that I had not tried using the AVERAGE function but I appreciate the suggestion, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use a Pivot Table. Insert a Pivot Table based on your data, then put Agent in the Rows, and Average of Time Spent in the values.

You can also use `SumIfs()/CountIfs` to get an average over a large dataset given specific criteria without needing to manually select the cells with the times to average. With this, you can select the entire data range and the formula will figure out which cells to include in the average based on the criteria you specify.

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,F2,$B$2:$B$5,G2)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,F2,$B$2:$B$5,G2)
```

[image]

Comment: The pivot table worked way way better than I could have imagined. Thank you so much. 

To elaborate, I created a Pivot table, and as you suggested, I added the Agent as in the Rows, and the Time Spent in the Values. Then I added the customer in the Column, and it basically outputted exactly what I was looking for. (I didn't include the average just now when I was testing, but it got me as far as I needed.) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything simpler than AVERAGEIF/AVERAGEIFS.

In G2 per image (and filled down),

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, A:A, E2, B:B, F2)
```

In G6 per image,

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, A:A, E6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your cells are formatted properly, you can just use `=AVERAGE()`:

[image: img1]

Comment: As above, this is a great suggestion, however it wasn't ideal for my user as it was a rather large data set and they wanted to do it in as few clicks as possible (imagine that!)